# A limit involving primes

Tags: limits, prime-numbers, products

I saw this limit at the PUMaC math competition this year:
If $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number, then find
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{p_n}{p_k}\right)^{p_n\over n(p_n+p_k)}$

I honestly have no idea how to approach it as primes don't have a simple pattern or formula.

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)
=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{p_n}{p_k}\right)^{p_n\over n(p_n+p_k)}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
g(n)
&=\ln(f(n))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {p_n\over n(p_n+p_k)}\ln\left(\frac{p_n}{p_k}\right)\\
&\sim\sum_{k=1}^\infty {n\ln(n)\over n(n\ln(n)+k\ln(k)+p_k)}\ln\left(\frac{n\ln(n)}{k\ln(k)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\ln(n)\over (n\ln(n)+k\ln(k))}\ln\left(\frac{n\ln(n)}{k\ln(k)}\right)\\
&\sim\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\ln(n)\over (n\ln(n)+k\ln(k))}(\ln(n)+\ln\ln(n)-\ln(k)-\ln\ln(k)))\\
\end{array}
$

For fixed $n$,
this behaves like
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\ln(n)\over (k\ln(k))}(-\ln(k))
=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\ln(n)\over k}
$
which diverges,
so $g(n) \to -\infty$
so $f(n) \to 0$.

If you take the limit
as $n \to \infty$ first,
you may get a different answer.

Comment: hmm there should be a actual value that is analytic, but how does the estimation of $p_n = n ln(n)$ work? It probably has something to do with the prime counting function right?